# Add table to a dataset

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Datatable add to dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438509/datatable-add-to-dataset)

I have dataset ds.. I need to check one of the values in the dataset and assign the value if satisfy criteria to another dataset. I can get the values but if assign to a dataset after checking the datatable dtreturn is not set to dsreturn. 
below is my code:

```
DataSet ds = datasetValue();

DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();            
DataTable dtReturn = dsReturn.Tables.Add();       
dtReturn.Columns.Add("id");           
dtReturn.Columns.Add("description");       
dtReturn.Columns.Add("status");           
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)    
{             
   if(Convert.ToInt32(row[1]) == status )          
   {
      DataRow newrowdata = dtReturn.NewRow();     

      // gives object ref not set to an instance of object...
      dsReturn.Tables["dtReturn"].ImportRow((row));

      //DataRow drReturn = dtReturn.NewRow();                
      //dsReturn.Tables["dtReturn"].Rows.Add(row);     
    }        
 }            
 return dsReturn;
```

Comment: [Didn't you just "ask" about this earlier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438509/datatable-add-to-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
DataTable dtReturn = dsReturn.Tables.Add();
```

Which would add a `DataTable` with a name something like Table1 or something else

```
dsReturn.Tables["dtReturn"].ImportRow((row));
```

here you are using the name which is actually the instance name of the DataTable not the one contained in the `DataSet`. No such Table as **dtReturn** exists in the `DataSet` dsReturn

Maybe adding this should do the trick `dtReturn.TableName = "dtReturn";`

Comment: i have modified the table name like                            dsReturn.Tables["Table1"].ImportRow((row));  but still getting the same error

Comment: Did you check by setting the `TableName` it need not be always Table1, also check what you get during Debug `dsReturn.Tables["Table1"]` should be null

Comment: i checked it .. it was Table1 during debugging..

Comment: So then you would be able to know which value was null, i think this should have worked.. did setting the TableName make any diff ?

Comment: nope..i have set the table name but still....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it different:

```
DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();

DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable("dtReturn");
dtReturn.Columns.Add("id");             
dtReturn.Columns.Add("description"); 
dtReturn.Columns.Add("status");

dsReturn.Tables.Add(dtReturn);
```

And what do you do with the newrowdata?

EDIT:

```
DataRow newrowdata = dtReturn.NewRow();
dsReturn.Tables["dtReturn"].ImportRow((newrowdata));
```

Comment: Why don't use this: DataRow newrowdata?